# Скрыть мобильное меню при нажатии на пункт (WP)

Tags: javascript, wordpress, menu, меню

В мобильной версии сайта меню раскрывается при нажатии на бургер и представляет собой вертикальный список пунктов (читай, кнопок) с соответствующими якорями на заголовки страницы.

При нажатии на любой пункт, сайт пролистывается до нужного участка (заголовка), но меню при этом остается открытым.

Скажите, как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на любой пункт меню, оно сворачивалось/закрывалось?

JS-код мобильного меню:

```js
//mobile-menu
    var winWidth = $(window).width();

    if (winWidth < 1025) {
        $('#menu-opener').click(function() {
            $('body').addClass('menu-open');

            $('.btn-close-menu').click(function() {
                $('body').removeClass('menu-open');
            });
        });

        $('.overlay').click(function() {
            $('body').removeClass('menu-open');
        });

        $('.main-navigation').prepend('<div class="btn-close-menu"></div>');

        $('.main-navigation ul .menu-item-has-children').append('<div class="angle-down"></div>');

        $('.main-navigation ul li .angle-down').click(function() {
            $(this).prev().slideToggle();
            $(this).toggleClass('active');
        });
    }

    if (winWidth > 1024){
        $("#site-navigation ul li a").focus(function() {
            $(this).parents("li").addClass("focus");
        }).blur(function() {
            $(this).parents("li").removeClass("focus");
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Без html не совсем понятно (что такое .overlay?), может стоит повесить на событие клика по кнопкам меню удаление класса removeClass('menu-open').

Comment: Прописывал removeClass('menu-open') со всеми элементами, что здесь есть - без толку

Comment: Насколько я понимаю меню показывается когда у body есть класс menu-open? Верно? И что он не удаляется если повесить событие клика на пункт меню? Чудес же не бывает

Comment: Возможно у Вас меню вложено в блок #menu-opener? Тогда при клике на пункт меню происходит всплытие события и меню остается открытым из за события родительского блока

Comment: Думаю, да, все верно. Что можно предпринять?

Comment: Запретить всплытие. Функцию обработчик клика по меню сделать такого вида function(e) { e.stopPropagation(); $('body'). removeClass('open-menu'); } Может где то ошибка, пишу с телефона, но суть такова

Answer (score 0):

Мой вариант:

```js
<script>
var menu = jQuery('.theme-main-menu');
var burger = menu.find('.navbar-toggle');
menu.find('.menu-item a').on('click', function(){
    if(!burger.hasClass('collapsed')){
        burger.trigger('click');
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]